# Who is Hræðraford, the "learned clerk" "writing in modern chemical Latin"?

Tags: thermodynamics, history-of-chemistry

> **This question has been re-asked on [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/):**
>   [Who is Hræðraford, the “learned clerk” “writing in modern chemical Latin”?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3581)

---

Truesdell, C. *Rational Thermodynamics*. New York, NY: Springer New York, 1984. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-5206-1, p. 41 says:

> … in the numerous papers and books whose titles and topics include "irreversible"—the learned clerk HRÆðRAFORD, writing in modern chemical Latin, has recently called their field "thermodynamice inreparabilis"—…

Who is this "learned clerk" Hræðraford?